# JUnit testing flywaydb using h2 database

Tags: java, junit, h2, flyway

I want to JUnit my migrations. I am setting up a H2 database in memory using `jdbc:h2:mem:./test` as url.

Flyway connects normally to database but fails to execute sql script giving me the following

```
com.nokia.avalanche.manager.migrations.FlywaydbWrap$MigrationException: Something happened in migration
at com.nokia.avalanche.manager.migrations.FlywaydbWrap.migrateDB(FlywaydbWrap.java:66)
at com.nokia.avalanche.manager.databasemanagement.FlywayDbMigrationTest.testIsDbCreated(FlywayDbMigrationTest.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: 
Migration V1__Base_version.sql failed
-------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 42000
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "LOCK[*] TABLES ""ENODEB"" WRITE "; SQL statement:
LOCK TABLES `enodeb` WRITE [42000-187]
Location   : db/migration/V1__Base_version.sql (D:\development\IPSL_source\trunk\myProject\target\classes\db\migration\V1__Base_version.sql)
Line       : 120
Statement  : LOCK TABLES `enodeb` WRITE

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:117)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:71)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$5.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:284)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$5.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:282)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigration(DbMigrate.java:282)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$800(DbMigrate.java:46)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:207)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:156)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:156)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1059)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1006)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418)
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006)
at com.nokia.avalanche.manager.migrations.FlywaydbWrap.migrateDB(FlywaydbWrap.java:63)
... 27 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "LOCK[*] TABLES ""ENODEB"" WRITE "; SQL statement:
LOCK TABLES `enodeb` WRITE [42000-187]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:191)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:518)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:476)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:305)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:281)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:242)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:461)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:403)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1189)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:170)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:238)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:114)
... 42 more
```

When I run flyway with the same sql scripts on my real MySql database it works normally no errors....Does H2 support Lock Tables?

Answer (score 3):

You might be using MySQL commands inside your flyway SQL scripts. I suggest to add to your H2 JDBC url the following string: `;MODE=MYSQL`

It might solve your problem if the commands used are supported by the MySQL compatibility mode of H2. If not, you're in a fix and you need to create H2 only flyway SQL scripts.

A word of caution: usage of H2 memory based databases with flyway may cause trouble to your JUnit. If the connection is closed, you cannot reopen it and find the content back.

Good luck with your experiments.

**Update**: LOCK seems unsupported in H2 even with `MODE=MYSQL`. It might confirm you need to write flyway SQL without MySQL specific commands.

Comment: Yes lock is not supported in H2...I get a new error of tables not existing, when they are used as fk to another table and created after that table. It works in sql...

Comment: @Apostolos could you share a sqlfiddle? or is your data model confidential/proprietary?

Comment: please show at least how the fk are created: a contrived example would do for 2 tables and 1 foreign key.

Comment: @ChristianMICHON Your answer might not have helped OP but it did help me, so thanks!